# PHP automatic generate names for input functions

Tags: php, html, automation

I'm writing some self generating HTML input tags, and I therefore need a way to speak to these, so that I can grab the text written by the user.

I have tried to do like this, but it doesn't seam to work as planed, any good ideas?

```
for ($i = 1; $1 <= 5; $1++) {
     $Content = $number.$i;
     $Sum = $_POST[$Content];
     $Total = $Total + $Sum
}
Echo $Total;
```

The idea here is that I have auto generated input functions named *"number1"*, *"number2"* and so on. I then want to grab all of those and get their value. Anybody knows a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I and many others have been down the path of variable variables when just learning, and yes it's possible.  But this is what arrays are for.  Define your inputs as an array:

```
<input type="text" name="number[]">
<input type="text" name="number[]">
```

Then just loop them:

```
$total = 0;
foreach($_POST['number'] as $number) {
    $total += $number;
}
```

If you want to define the key and use that for some reason:

```
<input type="text" name="number[1]">
<input type="text" name="number[2]">
```

Then you could use your style of loop or:

```
$total = 0;
foreach($_POST['number'] as $key => $number) {
    // use $key somehow
    $total += $number;
}
```

Comment: Awsome ! :D Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In for loop you are initiating/declared $i and $l incremented, which is not correct.
Semicolon (;) is missed. "$number" should be "number"

Use the below code.

```
$Total = '0';
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
     $Content = "number".$i;
     $Sum = $_POST[$Content];
     $Total = $Total + $Sum;
}
echo $Total;
```

Comment: Hey there :D 
Thanks for getting back to me - i can see that i never should have tried to explain it any different then it is :/ sorry about that 
The code look like this:

for($i=1;$i<6;$i++){
  $content = "$key" . $i;
  $pdf->Write(5, $content );
  $pdf->Ln($i);
 }

And the problem comes as the Write function takes in first an int and then a string: but i can't make it create and past through the string i desire :/ which is "key1", "key2" ,"key3" and so on